# rspec error for =~ expect syntax does not support operator matchers

Tags: rspec

getting

```
The expect syntax does not support operator matchers, 
so you must pass a matcher to `#to`.
```

For code that was

```
class_methods.all.should =~ [:bar, :hello]
```

that I wanted to change to

```
expect(class_methods.all).to =~ [:bar, :hello]
```

I also tried

```
expect(class_methods.all).to match [:bar, :hello]
```

and

```
expect(class_methods.all).to match ([:bar, :hello])
```

and

```
expect(class_methods.all match([:bar, :hello])).to be_true
# this one gives wrong number of arguments
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe the replacement of `=~` for arrays is [`match_array`](http://rubydoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-expectations/RSpec/Matchers%3amatch_array).

```
expect(class_methods.all).to match_array [:bar, :hello]
```

Answer (score 1):

you could try:

```
subject { class_methods.all }

it { should match_array [:bar, :hello] }
```

Answer (score 0):

And just to be clear, per https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-0/docs/built-in-matchers, while the new `expect` syntax supports a variety of comparison operators (e.g. `<`, `<=`, etc.) in conjunction with `be`, it does not support `=~` or `==`. The `match` method replaced `=~` for strings and regexes, with `match_array` handling the special case of arrays (per the other answer).